understand network I/O request and storage
I learned that for reading file, CPU would issue an I/O request to the hard disk, other hardware components would work on that requests and CPU is free to work on other commands.
My question would be what happens underlying the OS, after the CPU sends a get request to an endpoint. Example after doing
curl example.com

would CPU issue I/O requests to a hard disk or other storage device, and would some hardware try to listen for bytes transmitted in the network layer and store it somewhere?
Thanks

would CPU issue I/O requests to a hard disk or other storage device What does the hard drive have to do with the network? and would some hardware try to listen for bytes transmitted in the network layer and store it somewhere? No.

The real answer is "it depends on the hardware," but in general there will not be an automated way to transmit bytes directly from network card to hard drive.
"Curl" is a very complex program, if we're at the level of talking about what the CPU does or doesn't do.  We have to look at the underlying operations that it is doing in order to see the CPU's activity.
Let's say some bytes arrive from the network at your network interface card (NIC).  If you have a cheap card, your CPU may have to request bytes from the NIC directly, and then write them to memory.  However, some NICs support what is called Direct Memory Access (DMA).  DMA lets hardware like NICs and harddrives have direct access to the system memory.  If your NIC supports DMA, and the software took advantage of it, then the NIC could write all of the bytes in the packet into a "buffer" in memory, and then simply signal the CPU that there's a whole packet ready to work with.
The opposite pattern can happen with a harddrive.  If you don't have DMA, the CPU will have to copy bytes out of that buffer, one at a time, sending them to the harddrive.  If DMA is supported, it can instead simply direct the harddrive to store all of the bytes in the buffer onto the disk.
So if DMA is enabled for both boxes, the CPU doesn't have to read and write all of the bytes in the buffer.  It just needs to orchestrate the transfers.
In theory the NIC could transfer the bytes to the disk without any CPU usage, but it turns out this isn't all that useful.  It requires both the NIC and the harddrive to agree on a great many details about how to talk.  That standardization is hard, and expensive.  And it really doesn't take much CPU effort to direct traffic.  So we typically limit ourselves to DMA, where devices get to read/write to buffers in memory, and the CPU tells everyone where to go, one step at a time.
